# HTMLを踏むことでWebページを操作する方法について

Tags: html, coffeescript

別サイトの内容で恐縮なのですが、以下の記事に書かれているHTMLで何が行われているか解読できる方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
記事が書かれた時期と今では調整さんのつくりが変わっているようで書かれた手順でやってみてもできないのですが、「HTMLを踏むことでWebページを操作する」という部分を使いまわしたく考えておりまして、、

踏むだけで自動的に「調整さん」をたててくれる調整サンダー
https://qiita.com/sakamoto_akira_/items/f13f27d0873eca105c32

Comment: keitaro_so様、Fumu 7様、大変分かりやすい回答をいただきありがとうございます。

Comment: Fumu 7様、回答いただきありがとうございます。JavaScriptは少し使ったことがありますので、候補日程を作る部分を変えたくなった時に参考にさせていただきます！

Comment: keitaro_so様、回答いただきありがとうございます。「HTMLを踏むことで予め決まっているファームデータを作成して、そのデータを調整さんにPOSTする」という部分が、今回一番知りたかったことでした！教えていただきありがとうございます。また、CSRF対策がされていたらその方法は難しいかもしれないという点についても補足いただき助かりました。調整さんで手動で日程調整ページを作成しつつデベロッパーツールで通信の様子を見てみましたが、GET通信しか表示されなかったので対策されていそうでした。他の方法を探してみようと思います！

Answer (score 2):

参照先のURLですが、
「HTMLを踏むことでWebページを操作する」
のではなくて、正確にいうと
「HTMLを踏むことで予め決まっているフォームデータを作成して、そのデータを調整さんにPOSTする」というものです。

調整さんに設定しているフォームのデータを予め再現していますが、フォームの作りが変わったのか。はたまた、外からのPOSTを受け付けなくしたのかわかりませんが、機能はされなくなったようです。
再度調整さんのフォーム画面を解析して必要なパラメーターと項目の作りを参考にしながらフォームを作る必要がありそうです。

そもそも想定外からのPOSTを受け入れることは脆弱性の一つ
CSRFとよばれれて基本的に対策されるものですので、外からのPOSTは難しいものになるかもしれません。
https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/vuln/vuln_contents/csrf.html

Answer (score 0):

リンク先に記載されているHTMLのbody部分を見ると、formとスクリプト(プログラムのコード）部分があります。

スクリプト部分の最初に

```
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
```

と書かれていることから、それ以降のコードがcoffeeScriptという言語で書かれている事が判ります。

コードでは、２つのメソッド　collect_weekends と submit が定義され、最後("submit()"の行)でsubmitメソッドが呼び出されています。

＝＝
使いまわしたいという事であれば、まずcofeeScriptを勉強してください。JavaScriptをご存知なら、理解に苦しむことはないと思います。

coffeeScriptの基本を覚えたら、スクリプト部分のコードを理解して、自分の好みに改変することは難しくないでしょう。